# Loading JSON file with schema in spark is loading null data due to case sensitivity

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to load the JSON file with Schema but the columns of the schema are all of the lowercase and the keys in JSON file are not, so the data loaded is as null. 
I am able to load the file with the inferred schema but that is not an option.
I have also tried setting  `spark.sql.caseSensitive=true` but it didn't work rather added those as new columns.
Is there any property that can be set to make it work or do I have to preprocess all these JSON files before loading to spark.
JSON can have the missing key-values.
for e.g.

`{"id": "0001","type": "donut"}
 {"Id": "0002","Type": "Cakedonut"}
 {"ID": "0002"}`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no implicit setting that can combine your schema consider it as a feature of Spark you can use below code to achieve your goal.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive","true")
    val df = spark.read.json("src/main/resources/test.json")

    val finalColumns = df.columns.groupBy(_.toLowerCase)
      .map(t => functions.coalesce(t._2.map(col):_*).as(t._1))
      .toArray
    df.select(finalColumns: _*).show()
```

```
+---------+----+
|     type|  id|
+---------+----+
|    donut|0001|
|Cakedonut|0002|
|     null|0002|
+---------+----+
```